# How to fix "Syntax error on tokens, ( inspected instead"

Tags: java

I'm getting three errors stating Syntax error on tokens, ( expected instead

on line:
1)`return (int)(this.cities.stream().mapToDouble(x - > {`

2)`int cityIndex = this.cities.indexOf(x);`

3)`>}).sum() + this.cities.get(citiesSize - 1).measureDistance(this.cities.get(0)));`

any suggestions??

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Route {
    private ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();
    public Route(ArrayList<City> cities){
        this.cities.addAll(cities);
        Collections.shuffle(this.cities);
    }
    public Route(Route route){ this.cities.addAll(route.cities);}
    public ArrayList<City> getCities(){return cities;}
    public double getTotalDistance(){
        int citiesSize = this.cities.size();
        int x;
        return (int)(this.cities.stream().mapToDouble(x - > {
            int cityIndex = this.cities.indexOf(x);
            double returnValue = 0;
            if (cityIndex < citiesSize - 1)returnValue = x.measureDistance(this.cities.get(cityIndex + 1));
            return returnValue;
        }).sum() + this.cities.get(citiesSize - 1).measureDistance(this.cities.get(0)));
    }
    public String getTotalStringDistance(){
        String returnValue = String.format("%.2f",this.getTotalDistance());
        if (returnValue.length() == 7) return " " +returnValue;
        return returnValue;
    }
    public String toString(){ return Arrays.toString(cities.toArray());}
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what type error you getting and you might be space here - >

Comment: You have a space in the lambda operator, instead of `- >` use `->` (in the line `return (int)(this.cities.stream().mapToDouble(x - > {`). You will also need to remove `int x;`

Comment: Apart from ☝️You have named a variable `x` using `int x;` and trying to use a variable named `x` again in the lambda.

Comment: Your title does not agree with your question. If you can't post the error message accurately you can't expect accurate answers.

Comment: Please add comments on the lines you get the errors in the code snippet you show. And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score -1):

For 1) `return (int)(this.cities.stream().mapToDouble(x - > {` ---- remove space between - and >. 
it should be `return (int)(this.cities.stream().mapToDouble(x -> {`

2) `int cityIndex = this.cities.indexOf(x);` --- As x is already used in the method. try using another variable

for 3-- can you please mention the error.